# Work with GridUnitType.Star in Grid column converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a converter to fill the remaining space of a hidden column in WPF (set width to 0.0), but in fact I need the ratio `1.7*` vs `*` if visible! 
How can I calculate the real value to set for the converter?

**Converter:**

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var isVisible = (bool) value;
        var width = parameter as string == "*" 
            ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star).Value
            : double.Parse(parameter as string);            

        return isVisible ? width : 0.0;            
    }


    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

}
```

As you can see I tried with `new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star).Value`but it's not the correct way!

**XAML** (condensed):

```
<appf:ViewUserControl.Resources>        
    <local:ColumnWidthConverter x:Key="ColumnWidthConverter" />
</appf:ViewUserControl.Resources>


<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>               
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.7*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=Visible, Converter={StaticResource ColumnWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=*}"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

`Visible` is just a boolean property in the corresponding ViewModel!

Comment: You have to parse `parameter` to get number of star units from it and pass it as double to that `GridLength` constructor overload.

Comment: There is a [GridLengthConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlengthconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) (it seems it uses [XamlGridLengthSerializer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/GridLengthConverter.cs,b5660a9b1a964e50) to parse the string containing star units).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's easy: use string instead of double value

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var isVisible = (bool) value;
        var width = parameter as string;           

        return isVisible ? width : "0.0";            
    }


    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

}
```